# What are the episode titles of Boku no Imouto wa "Oosaka Okan" parodying?

Tags: boku-no-imouto-wa-osaka-okan

Listed below are all the episode titles from the [official site](http://www.imouto-okan.jp/) (in Japanese). The title for the limited time episode on NicoNico is taken from the [official (?) blog](http://imoutookan.seesaa.net/article/311387586.html) (in Japanese):

> Episode 1: ある朝、大阪おかんの妹ができまして。 (Aru Asa, Oosaka Okan no Imouto ga Dekimashite)
>   Episode 2: 妹が大阪おかんなんですけど！ (Imouto ga Oosaka Okan Nandesu Kedo!)
>   Episode 3: 俺の妹がこんなに大阪おかんなわけがない (Ore no Imouto ga Konna ni Oosaka Okan na Wake ga Nai)
>   Episode 4: 大阪おかんだけど愛さえあれば関係ないよねっ (Oosaka Okan Dakedo Ai Sae Areba Kankei Nai yo ne)
>   Episode 5: 大阪おかんホーム (Oosaka Okan Home)
>   Episode 6: 最近、妹のようすがちょっと大阪おかんなんだが。 (Saikin, Imouto no Yousu ga Chotto Oosaka Okan Nandaga.)
>   Episode 7: この中に１人、大阪おかんがいる！ (Kono Naka ni Hitori, Oosaka Okan ga Iru!)
>   Episode 8: あるいは現在進行形の大阪おかん (Arui wa Genzaishinkoukei no Oosaka Okan)
>   Episode 9: 大阪おかんな妹と受難な俺 (Oosaka Okan na Imouto to Ju'nan na Ore)
>   Episode 10: 妹は大阪おかんの女神ちゃん (Imouto wa Oosaka Okan no Megami-chan)
>   Episode 11: 最近の大阪おかんブームはどうやら俺のおかげらしいですよ (Saikin no Oosaka Okan Boom wa Douyara Ore no Okage Rashii Desuyo)
>   Episode 12: 浪花はん＠がんばらない (Namika-han@Ganbaranai)
>
> Episode 1.5: 配信限定大阪おかん (Haishin Gentei Oosaka Okan)

Some episode titles can be easily recognized as a parody of the names of several light novel/manga series. It is interesting that the original series usually have something to do with brother-sister relation:

> [俺の妹がこんなに可愛いわけがない (Ore no Imouto ga Konna ni Kawaii Wake ga Nai)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oreimo)
>   ==> Episode 3: 俺の妹がこんなに大阪おかんなわけがない (Ore no Imouto ga Konna ni Oosaka Okan na Wake ga Nai)
>
> [お兄ちゃんだけど愛さえあれば関係ないよねっ (Onii-chan dakedo Ai sae Areba Kankeinai yo ne!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniai)
>   ==> Episode 4: 大阪おかんだけど愛さえあれば関係ないよねっ (Oosaka Okan Dakedo Ai Sae Areba Kankei Nai yo ne)
>
> [最近、妹のようすがちょっとおかしいんだが。 (Saikin, Imouto no Yousuga Chotto Okashiindaga.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imocho) <sup>[[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV3PY.jpg)</sup>
>   ==> Episode 6: 最近、妹のようすがちょっと大阪おかんなんだが。 (Saikin, Imouto no Yousu ga Chotto Oosaka Okan Nandaga.)
>
> [この中に１人、妹がいる！ (Kono Naka ni Hitori, Imouto ga Iru!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakaimo)
>   ==> Episode 7: この中に１人、大阪おかんがいる！ (Kono Naka ni Hitori, Oosaka Okan ga Iru!)
>
> [ささみさん@がんばらない (Sasami-san@Ganbaranai)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasami-san@Ganbaranai)
>   ==> Episode 12: 浪花はん＠がんばらない (Namika-han@Ganbaranai)

I believe most or all of the titles must be a parody of some existing series.

**What are the rest of the titles parody of?**

**Update:** I have identified all of the main episodes' titles. However, I cannot find any work that resembles Episode 1.5: 配信限定大阪おかん.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some googling, it turns out that all of the episode titles are parodies of the names of light novel series that have a big brother ― younger sister theme:

> [ある朝、ヒーローの妹ができまして。](http://dash.shueisha.co.jp/bookDetail/index/978-4-08-630652-2) <sup>[[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4086306522) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1M6e.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 1: ある朝、大阪おかんの妹ができまして。
>
> [妹がゾンビなんですけど！](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A6%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%82%BE%E3%83%B3%E3%83%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9!) <sup>[[スマッシュ文庫]](http://www.php.co.jp/smash/books/2012/03/post-7.php) [[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4569676472/) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxAu9.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 2: 妹が大阪おかんなんですけど！
>
> [妹ホーム（マイホーム）](http://dengekibunko.dengeki.com/newreleases/978-4-04-870881-4/) <sup>[[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4048708813) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQgbl.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 5: 大阪おかんホーム
>
> [あるいは現在進行形の黒歴史](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E9%80%B2%E8%A1%8C%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%AE%E9%BB%92%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2) <sup>[[GA文庫]](http://ga.sbcr.jp/novel/kurorekishi/) [[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4797361476) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zrox.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 8: あるいは現在進行形の大阪おかん
>
> [女子モテな妹と受難な俺](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%90%E3%83%A2%E3%83%86%E3%81%AA%E5%A6%B9%E3%81%A8%E5%8F%97%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%AA%E4%BF%BA) <sup>[[ガガガ文庫]](http://www.shogakukan.co.jp/books/volumes/_id_26208) [[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4094512411) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQqv.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 9: 大阪おかんな妹と受難な俺
>
> [妹はラノベの女神ちゃん](http://www.php.co.jp/smash/books/2012/08/post-24.php) <sup>[[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4569678289/) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAOU5.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 10: 妹は大阪おかんの女神ちゃん
>
> [最近の妹ブームはどうやら俺のおかげらしいですよ](http://data.ichijinsha.co.jp/book/booksearch/booksearch_detail.php?i=75804326) <sup>[[Amazon]](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4758043264) [[Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPeQD.jpg)</sup>
>   ⇒ Episode 11: 最近の大阪おかんブームはどうやら俺のおかげらしいですよ

**I still don't know whether the special episode (episode 1.5) is parody of any existing work or not.**

Comment: 配信限定 means "limited release/distribution" or "limited edition"

Comment: @Krazer: Well, it probably means that it is not a parody, then. (I recognized the 限定 as limited - so I had a hunch that it might not be a parody).